# in shiny, when i convert this logo to action button, a gray background appear, how to fix this

Tags: r, shiny

as the image here,

[image]
<sub>(source: [qhmqk.me](https://shiny.qhmqk.me/ui-input/actionbuttons-with-icon-and-img.png))</sub>

gray background appears once i convert the logo to action button, i need the logo to be transparent
once again, before converting the image to action button there is no background and the logo area is totally transparent

```
title <- tags$a(href= NULL, tags$button(id = "shinylogo",class = "btn action-button", img(src ="BM_fl.png",height = '55',  style = "padding-bottom:20px;border-radius: 0px;
                   border-width: 0px")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the UI side, use this

```
  title <- tags$a(href= "", id = "logo",tags$img(src ="fl.png",width= '120',  style = "padding-bottom:30px;vertical-align: middle;border-radius: 0px;border-width: 0px"))
```

in the server side use this ,

```
 observeEvent(input$logo,{updateSelectInput(session,"listofitems","Items List", choices =c("Home","Group","Clients","Banks"), selected = "Home")},ignoreInit = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could overwrite the `background-color` property by adding some additional CSS. Working example below, hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$a(href= NULL, 
         tags$button(id = "shinylogo",
                     class = "btn action-button", 
                     style='background-color:transparent',
                     img(src ="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/139-1398300_r-shiny-logo.png",
                         height = '55',  
                         style = "padding-bottom:20px;border-radius: 0px;border-width: 0px"
                     )
         )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```